# Not outputting correct echos depending on value chosen from drop down menu

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, echo

I want to output the value from a dropdown menu using an echo but even though the dropdown menu works perfectly, the echo is not outputting the right value chosen from the drop down menu. The echo only output Session ID and that is it. Can you help me with this please. The echo is at the bottom of the code.

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<title>Exam Interface</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

<p><strong>NOTE: </strong>If a search box is left blank, then the form will search for all data under that specific field</p>

<form action="exam_interface.php" method="post" name="sessionform">        <!-- This will post the form to its own page"-->
<p>Session ID: <input type="text" name="sessionid" /></p>      <!-- Enter Session Id here-->
<p>Module Number: <input type="text" name="moduleid" /></p>      <!-- Enter Module Id here-->
<p>Teacher Username: <input type="text" name="teacherid" /></p>      <!-- Enter Teacher here-->
<p>Student Username: <input type="text" name="studentid" /></p>      <!-- Enter User Id here-->
<p>Grade: <input type="text" name="grade" /></p>      <!-- Enter Grade here-->
<p>Order Results By: <select name="order">
<option value="ordersessionid">Session ID</option>
<option value="ordermoduleid">Module Number</option>
<option value="orderteacherid">Teacher Username</option>
<option value="orderstudentid">Student Username</option>
<option value="ordergrade">Grade</option>
</select>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" /></p>
</form>

<?php

$username="u0867587";
$password="31may90";
$database="mobile_app";

mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);

@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");

$sessionid = isset ($_POST['sessionid']) ? $_POST['sessionid'] : "";
$moduleid = isset ($_POST['moduleid']) ? $_POST['moduleid'] : "";
$teacherid = isset ($_POST['teacherid']) ? $_POST['teacherid'] : "";
$studentid = isset ($_POST['studentid']) ? $_POST['studentid'] : "";
$grade = isset ($_POST['grade']) ? $_POST['grade'] : "";
$orderfield = isset ($_POST['order']) ? $_POST['order'] : "";

$sessionid = mysql_real_escape_string($sessionid);
$moduleid = mysql_real_escape_string($moduleid);
$teacherid = mysql_real_escape_string($teacherid);
$studentid = mysql_real_escape_string($studentid);
$grade = mysql_real_escape_string($grade);

switch ($orderfield) {
    case 'ordersessionid': $orderfield = 'gr.SessionId';
    break;
    case 'ordermoduleid': $orderfield = 'm.ModuleId'; 
    break;
    case 'orderteacherid': $orderfield = 's.TeacherId';
    break;
    case 'orderstudentid': $orderfield = 'gr.StudentId'; 
    break;
    case 'ordergrade': $orderfield = 'gr.Grade';
    break;
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Module m INNER JOIN Session s ON m.ModuleId = s.ModuleId JOIN Grade_Report gr ON s.SessionId = gr.SessionId JOIN Student st ON gr.StudentId = st.StudentId WHERE ('$sessionid' = '' OR gr.SessionId = '$sessionid') AND ('$moduleid' = '' OR m.ModuleId = '$moduleid') AND ('$teacherid' = '' OR s.TeacherId = '$teacherid') AND ('$studentid' = '' OR gr.StudentId = '$studentid') AND ('$grade' = '' OR gr.Grade = '$grade') ORDER BY $orderfield ASC");

$num=mysql_numrows($result);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

echo "<p>Your Search: <strong>Session ID:</strong> "; if (empty($sessionid))echo "'All Sessions'"; else echo "'$sessionid'";echo ", <strong>Module ID:</strong> "; if (empty($moduleid))echo "'All Modules'"; else echo "'$moduleid'";echo ", <strong>Teacher Username:</strong> "; if (empty($teacherid))echo "'All Teachers'"; else echo "'$teacherid'";echo ", <strong>Student Username:</strong> "; if (empty($studentid))echo "'All Students'"; else echo "'$studentid'";echo ", <strong>Grade:</strong> "; if (empty($grade))echo "'All Grades'"; else echo "'$grade'"; echo ", <strong>Order Results By:</strong>";if ($orderfield = 'gr.SessionId') echo " 'Session ID'"; else if ($orderfield = 'ordermoduleid') echo " 'Module Number' "; else if ($orderfield = 's.TeacherId') echo " 'Teacher Username' "; else if ($orderfield = 'gr.StudentId') echo " 'Student Username' "; else if ($orderfield = 'gr.Grade') echo " 'Grade' ";"</p>";

mysql_close();


 ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Unless it is off screen somewhere, there doesn't appear to be a closing `}` for `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every instance, you overwrite `$orderfield` because you are using `=` instead of `==`.  Rather than testing the value of `$odrerfield`, you are *assigning* the value of `$orderfield`.

```
if ($orderfield = 'gr.SessionId')

// Should be
if ($orderfield == 'gr.SessionId')
```

Make the same change for all the instances that follow.  It is highly advisable to break up that long echo line into multiple lines.

```
echo "<p>Your Search: <strong>Session ID:</strong> "; 
if (empty($sessionid))echo "'All Sessions'"; 
else echo "'$sessionid'";
echo ", <strong>Module ID:</strong> "; 
if (empty($moduleid))echo "'All Modules'"; 
else echo "'$moduleid'";
echo ", <strong>Teacher Username:</strong> "; 
if (empty($teacherid))echo "'All Teachers'"; 
else echo "'$teacherid'";
echo ", <strong>Student Username:</strong> "; 
if (empty($studentid))echo "'All Students'"; 
else echo "'$studentid'";
echo ", <strong>Grade:</strong> "; 
if (empty($grade))echo "'All Grades'"; 
else echo "'$grade'"; 
echo ", <strong>Order Results By:</strong>";
if ($orderfield == 'gr.SessionId') echo " 'Session ID'"; 
else if ($orderfield == 'ordermoduleid') echo " 'Module Number' "; 
else if ($orderfield == 's.TeacherId') echo " 'Teacher Username' "; 
else if ($orderfield == 'gr.StudentId') echo " 'Student Username' "; 
else if ($orderfield == 'gr.Grade') echo " 'Grade' ";"</p>";
```

Comment: OMG I can't believe I missed that. Thank you it worked perfectly

Comment: @user992147 Please accept the answer if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

```
cho "<p>Your Search: <strong>Session ID:</strong> "; if (empty($sessionid))echo "'All Sessions'"; else echo "'$sessionid'";echo ", <strong>Module ID:</strong> "; if (empty($moduleid))echo "'All Modules'"; else echo "'$moduleid'";echo ", <strong>Teacher Username:</strong> "; if (empty($teacherid))echo "'All Teachers'"; else echo "'$teacherid'";echo ", <strong>Student Username:</strong> "; if (empty($studentid))echo "'All Students'"; else echo "'$studentid'";echo ", <strong>Grade:</strong> "; if (empty($grade))echo "'All Grades'"; else echo "'$grade'"; echo ", <strong>Order Results By:</strong>";if ($orderfield = 'gr.SessionId') echo " 'Session ID'"; else if ($orderfield = 'ordermoduleid') echo " 'Module Number' "; else if ($orderfield = 's.TeacherId') echo " 'Teacher Username' "; else if ($orderfield = 'gr.StudentId') echo " 'Student Username' "; else if ($orderfield = 'gr.Grade') echo " 'Grade' ";"</p>";
```

You have used wrong compare operator on the if condition above, like -  if($orderfield = 'ordermoduleid'), these will be like - if($orderfield == 'ordermoduleid')

Comment: OMG I can't believe I missed that. Thank you it worked perfectly